# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable (DjangoAdmin)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I am trying to register one of my Models in the Django admin page (code below):

```
class Collection(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    featured_product = models.ForeignKey(
        'Product', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='+')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['title']
```

code from admin.py:

```
@admin.site.register(models.Collection)
class CollectionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['title', 'products_count']

    def products_count(self, collection):
        return collection.products_count

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return super().get_queryset(request).annotate(products_count=Count)
```

But I get this error for the collection Model for some reason and for no other model that i registered.

Traceback:

```
C:\Users\jonas_6xnnk8f\PycharmProjects\storefront\store\admin.py changed, reloading.
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python39_64\lib\threading.py", line 980, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python39_64\lib\threading.py", line 917, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jonas_6xnnk8f\PycharmProjects\djangoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jonas_6xnnk8f\PycharmProjects\djangoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\jonas_6xnnk8f\PycharmProjects\djangoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Users\jonas_6xnnk8f\PycharmProjects\djangoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 394, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Users\jonas_6xnnk8f\PycharmProjects\djangoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jonas_6xnnk8f\PycharmProjects\djangoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\jonas_6xnnk8f\PycharmProjects\djangoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 124, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "C:\Users\jonas_6xnnk8f\PycharmProjects\djangoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\apps.py", line 27, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "C:\Users\jonas_6xnnk8f\PycharmProjects\djangoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\__init__.py", line 50, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules("admin", register_to=site)
  File "C:\Users\jonas_6xnnk8f\PycharmProjects\djangoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 58, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module("%s.%s" % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python39_64\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\jonas_6xnnk8f\PycharmProjects\storefront\store\admin.py", line 38, in <module>
    class CollectionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the error—the problem was that I typed `@admin.site.register(models.Collection)` instead of `@admin.register(models.Collection)`.